# Python 2.7 easy_install - the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process error

Tags: python, python-2.7, easy-install, yappi

Using Python I am trying to install a library called [yappi](https://code.google.com/archive/p/yappi/) through easy_install. However I am getting this error below on Windows 7 Command Shell:

[image]

I explored alternative installations. I tried previously 'pip install yappi' but this didn't work due to a separate error (can't build wheel) which is a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the appropriate wheel from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#yappi).

Then use `pip install [package]`.